# Client does not received message from socket js server

Tags: unity-game-engine, websocket, uwp, socket.io, hololens

I am working on to establish a message communication between UWP Application on desktop and the Hololens 1.

According to the implementation of Websockets from Microsoft Documentation [Websocket Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets) I could 
implement the signalling part to the Nodejs with socket.io Server

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});


var PORT = 3000;
var userId = 0;

http.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('listening on *: ' + PORT);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.userId = userId++;
    console.log('a user connected, user id: ' + socket.userId);

    socket.on('mess', function (msg) {
    console.log('message from user#' + socket.userId + ": " + msg);
    // Send message with emit"mess" to all client
    io.emit('mess', msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

Both client (uwp app and the hololens could establish to the Server.
On the computer I could send some data to the server. 
The problem I currently have is that the Hololens does not receive a message from the server.

For the communication part I use a wrapper class which provide sending and receiving functions for 2 clients. This wrapper class has been generated to dll inorder to reference in 2 difference projekt (uwp app and unity app for hololens)

```
// Declare "Using" part here...

namespace SocketWrapperNamespace
{

    public delegate void OnReceiveMessengerCallback(string msg);
    public delegate void OnDisconnectCallback(bool connect);

    public class SocketWrapper
    {
        public event OnReceiveMessengerCallback OnReceiveMessenger;
        public event OnDisconnectCallback onDisconnect;

#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        private Uri _uri;
        private MessageWebSocket messageWebSocket;
        private DataWriter dataWriter;
#endif
        // Client can call this function to connect
        public void Connect(string uri)
        {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            try
            {
                Connector(uri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
#endif
        }

        private async void Connector(string uri)
        {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
           // Code here look pretty much like in the example from microsoft documentation
#endif
        }

        // Function for client to send message to server
        public void SendMessage(string emiter, string message)
        {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            try
            {
                Emit(emiter, message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
#endif
        }


        //Emitter
        private async void Emit(string emiter, string message)
        {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            try
            {
                if (messageWebSocket == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (dataWriter == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                string form = string.Format("42[\"{0}\",\"{1}\"]", emiter, message);

                dataWriter.WriteString(form);
                await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
#endif
        }

        //Disconnect
        public void Disconnect()
        {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
          // Disconnecting server ...
#endif
        }

        //Message Arrived Handler
        private void WebSocket_MessageArrived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            try
            {
                if (OnReceiveMessenger == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                using (DataReader dataReader = args.GetDataReader())
                {
                    if (dataReader != null)
                    {
                        dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                        string message = dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                        OnReceiveMessenger?.Invoke(message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
#endif
        }

        //Websocket Close Handler
        private void WebSocket_Closed(IWebSocket sender, WebSocketClosedEventArgs args)
        {
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
            // Close work here ...
#endif
    }
}
```

**On the Hololens I prepare the connection to server and listen to the received message event.**

```
// hololens client call this method to initialize the connection
public void OnStart()
    {
        socketWrapper = new SocketWrapper();
        uri = String.Concat("ws://",server,":3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket");
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
        socketWrapper.Connect(uri);
        socketWrapper.OnReceiveMessenger += OnMessageArrived_Handler;
        socketWrapper.onDisconnect += OnDisconnect_Handler;
#endif
    }

//Message Arrived Handler
    private void OnMessageArrived_Handler(string msg)
    {
// Here I do not received any message from server
}
```

What mistake did I make her ? I wonder that even though I can connect to the server from hololens but the subscribe part seem not to work ?
Consider the 2 projects are on different location and the same happen to the dll.

**I think that I have to setup the SocketWrapper class as Singleton because hololens part instantiate a new Object therefor the subscribing may not work here**

Any better suggestion for solve this problem with other implementation would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution now for using WebSocket in C# and Unity environment is [WebSocketSharp library](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp).
It has a great implementation and kept up to date for 6 years till now. Also it has 3 examples of how to use it in different scenarios.

Comment: I am considering to implement with MQTT but yeah probably I could give it a try with your suggestion.

Comment: @user7112196 did you manage to establish connection between uwp app and hololens?